# Why my IsMouseOver style doing nothing in my controller style

Tags: wpf, mahapps.metro

So i have this `Style`:

```
xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"

<Style TargetType="Controls:NumericUpDown">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF307AE4"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Gray"/>
        </Trigger>

        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Gainsboro"/>
        </Trigger>

        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Gray"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

i define several color and Want to change `IsMouseOver` property but t seems that this not effect at all.

`IsEnabled` workd fine.

What i am doing wrong ?

Comment: What is the code for `Controls:NumericUpDown`? You should apply your styling inside this `NumericUpDown` instead. It might not even have any `BorderBrush` property at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if you are also setting BorderBrush property in your control thinking that it will set some initial value. This will always take precedence above any changes done via your style.

I have tried below code :

```
<Controls:NumericUpDown Minimum = "0" Maximum = "10000" Interval = "5" StringFormat="C2" Padding="5">
            <Controls:NumericUpDown.Style>
                <Style TargetType="Controls:NumericUpDown">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Pink"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow"/>
                    </Trigger>                  

                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="DeepSkyBlue"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="3"/>
                        </Trigger>

                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Cornsilk"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Purple"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="3"/>
                        </Trigger>

                    </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
            </Controls:NumericUpDown.Style>
        </Controls:NumericUpDown>
```

and mouse-over border effects are not visible at all. Background is working well, but BorderBrush, BorderThickness doesn't working at all. This is surely a bug.

But things change when we apply some style like given on this page. But still  borderbrush doesn't change. But BorderThickness works correctly. You can experiment. I will update more once I become familiar with this.

http://mahapps.com/guides/styles.html#app

Comment: No, this define only inside my style

Comment: @markyer borderthickness is must for border related things to show up. see my edited answer though.

Comment: @markyer it is related to style , i have updated my answer again, as i am using MahaApps first time. you can experiment more with styles.

Comment: That's strange, when mouse is over: BorderBrush become Gray

Comment: @markyer you can submit your issues here https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro